# Special Json Output format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I use **SQL Server 2017** and I want to send many records to external web service  in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) form .
I don,t want repeat columns name for every row in json form .
To **reduce** the size of output JSON,I want to put all **columns name** in first row and put **just columns values** to another rows.
I want to create below structure for my **output json** :

```
  {
    "data": [
        ["col1name", "col2name", "col3name"],
        ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
        ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    ]
}
```

This json format is valid and Valiated on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)
I want to create this structue in sql server but I don,t know HOW ?
Is there any idea about it ?

Comment: My problem is how to create this json format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, the only way I can think to do this would be with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
CREATE TABLE V (Col1 varchar(10), Col2 varchar(10),Col3 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO V    
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('value1','value2','value3'),
            ('value1','value2','value3')) V(Col1, Col2, Col3);

DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX);

SET @JSON = N'{' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            N'   "data": [' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            N'       [' + STUFF((SELECT N', ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'"')
                                 FROM sys.columns c
                                      JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                                 WHERE t.[name] = N'V'
                                 ORDER BY c.column_id ASC
                                 FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'') + N'],' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                          N'       [' + QUOTENAME(Col1,'"') + N', ' + QUOTENAME(Col2,'"') + N', ' + QUOTENAME(Col3,'"') + N']'
                   FROM V
                   ORDER BY V.Col1
                   FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            N'    ]' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
            N'}';

PRINT @JSON;

DROP TABLE V;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd75f1da33f840271ef40c50e9759e00)

Someone may know a way to do this with `FOR JSON`; but I'm not sure you can, without some play.

Comment: Perhaps, even difficult in Sql Server as its very complex already.